# Fecthing a json object using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am working with an API that contains information in the below format:

```
[
{Key1: Value1,
 Key2: Value2A,
 Key3: Value3A,
 Key4: Value4A},
{Key1: Value1,
 Key2: Value2B,
 Key3: Value3B,
 Key4: Value4B},
{Key1: Value1,
 Key2: Value2C,
 Key3: Value3C,
 Key4: Value4C}
]
```

I am trying to fetch the value of Key3 based on the value of Key2. I know what the value of Key2 will be but Key3's value is generated during runtime. I want to compare the value of Key2 and if it matches return the value of Key3 from that object.

I tried using streams after reading throught about it online, but I am not able to fetch either the entire object nor that particular value as a string.

Here is what I've tried which returns absolutely nothing:

```
public static String fetchCarModel(String value2A) {

    final Optional<CarModel> carModel =  Car.api().models().list().stream()
            .filter(r -> r.getKey().equals(value2A)) // Check for the correct object
            .findAny();

    return carModel.get().getId();
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: you've passed a parameter `merchantKey` but you're not using it. where is `yearKey` coming from?

Comment: @Aominè Sorry, updated the code again.

Comment: yearKey is something the user would give as input which in our example above be equal to any of the Key2 values.

Comment: So what I'm trying to achieve here is match the Key2 values based on user input and fetch the corresponding value of Key3 or Key1 in that object. I hope I am clear.

Comment: don't you just want `.filter(carModel -> carModel.getKey2().equals(value2A))` and then pull the value of `Key3` from the `carModel` ?

Comment: and what do you mean "returns absolutely nothing" ? do you get an exception or is the return value from the method an empty string? or is the API call returning no results?

Comment: When I meant returns nothing, it returns an empty string. Do you think the return statement is wrong. From this: .filter(carModel -> carModel.getKey2().equals(value2A)) I get the object, but how do I fetch the particular value ?

Comment: Isn’t it simply return carModel.get().getKey3(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the call to `Car.api().models().list()` returns a `List<CarModel>` where `CarModel` has the four aforementioned properties.

In that case, to achieve the said requirement you can do the following:

```
public static String fetchCarModel(String value2A) {    
    final Optional<CarModel> carModel =  Car.api().models().list().stream()
            .filter(carModel -> carModel.getKey2().equals(value2A)) // Check for the correct object
            .findAny();   

    return carModel.get().getKey3(); // get the value of this property
}
```

Note,  you should only call `Optional.get()` if you're sure there will be a value present in the `Optional<T>` otherwise it's better to utilise `orElse` or `orElseGet` to unwrap the value if present else provide a default value.

Ideally, a better approach would be to change the method signature to return an `Optional<String>` and then let the caller of this API decide what to do in the no value case.

- See the [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) API for more details.
- See this post about the [`Optional<T>`](http://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) type if you're unfamiliar with it.